# cannot match substring using regex_search

Tags: c++, regex, stl

Why this is failing ? I am trying to match a substring using regex in C++STL.
What I am doing wrong here ?

GCC Version :: (Linaro GCC 4.8-2014.04) 4.8.3

```
#include<regex>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        regex e("auth");
        smatch m;
        string s="Connected to a:b:c:d completed auth id=3, str=3";
        //string s="auth";

        bool match = regex_search(s,e);
        if( match == true )
                printf("matched");
        else
                printf("no match");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [std::regex_match](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) only matches the *whole* string. You probably want [std::regex_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search)

```
#include<regex>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        regex e("auth");
        smatch m;
        string s="Connected to a:b:c:d completed auth id=3, str=3";
        //string s="auth";

        bool match = regex_search(s,e);
        if( match == true )
                printf("matched");
        else
                printf("no match");
}
```

Also you should check if your implementation supports `std::regex` which is a new feature in `C++11`. For example the `GCC` compiler only properly implements `<regex>` in versions `4.9.0` and above.

Comment: I have used regex_search also. It gives me the same result

Comment: @KrishnaM This code works for me, perhaps your compiler does not fully support regex? If using GCC need v4.9.0 or above, not sure about other compilers.

Comment: Works ok here: http://ideone.com/vAnj7h

Comment: I am using GCC Version 4.8.3

Comment: @KrishnaM Then that's the problem :)